# Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать текст воспринимаемым

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, стилистика

Речь о сравнении капеллы св. Сильвестра (Рим) и Спасо-Преображенского Мирожского монастыря (Псков).

Ничего не правила, только глазнушки убрала, п/ж - мои претензии автору, ещё не отправленные.

> Интересно сравнить подход *Рима* **(вот зачем курсив?)** с подходом
>   наших богословов и мастеров из Мирожского монастыря во Пскове (эти
>   памятники – ровесники, **вторая половина двенадцатого столетия - ЭТО
>   ОТСЕБЯТИНКА, чтоб дальше понятно было!)**. Настоятелем нашего
>   монастыря был грек, мастера – *ромеи,* как сами звали себя жители бывшей
>   Империи. И ведь насколько один образный язык оказывается более развит
>   и богат к XIII столетию, чем другой **(я потеряла нить: какие языки
>   сравниваются? Ты ж молчишь о: год основания Мирожского монастыря. Нам
>   непонятно, откуда сравнение с XIII столетием!)**! И здесь и там в
>   сценах, в позах  присутствует церемониальность **(не:
>   церемонность?)**, чудится привкус придворного искусства. И здесь и там
>   фигуры изнежены, бестелесны, чуть касаются земли. И здесь и там
>   художник обнаруживает ракурс **(КАКОЙ?!)** и часто пользуется им
>   скорей как знаком **(КАКИМ?!)**, чем ориентируется на требования композиции. И здесь
>   и там перед нами суть – византийское искусство. Однако Рим обращается
>   ко зрителю почти по-варварски: грубовато, зато доходчиво. И если
>   сосредоточиться, то смысл ясен даже нам – совершенным вандалам, с
>   позиций средневекового человека.

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать красиво - мы ж уже почти разобрались, кто на ком стоял.

Вот етое: *суть – византийское искусство* - просто безжалостно выкидываем тире? Перед *с позиций* запятую можно оставить?

*Художник обнаруживает ракурс и часто пользуется им скорей как знаком, чем ориентируется на требования композиции,* - ничего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерес представляет сотворчество мастеров-ромеев, как сами звали себя жители бывшей империи, и отцов Мирожского монастыря. Ещё не ведающие новейших проявлений, сторонящиеся и не желающие принимать ничего иного, нарочитого, грубого в своей натуралистичности, позёрстве, свойственным придворной портретной и сюжетной живописи, они, как и грек-настоятель, отстаивали традиции Церкви. И теперь перед нами — суть византийское в своей чистоте искусство, где образы эфемерны, фигуры чуть касаются земли, композиции статичны. В них нет и тени той церемониальности и сложных ракурсов, которые позже проникли из светского гуманистического искусства в ренессансные храмы.

Это канва, не более.